# How to add xmlns to message in savon

Tags: soap, savon

I am using savon 2 gem. How to add the xmlns to message tag instead of envelope?

The xml generate is this

`<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:tns="http://www.serviceurl.com/">
    <soap:Body>
       <tns:Search>
         <Token>55</Token>
       </tns:Search>
    </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>`

I need this

`<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
       <Search xmlns="http://www.serviceurl.com/">
          <Token>55</Token>
       </Search>
    </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>`

i.e **Search xmlns="http://www.serviceurl.com/"**

Answer (score 2):

I have a very simple solution for that.
Just use a string as the tag and specify the namespace.
You missed sharing your code, so I can only guess what it might look like, but you should change it to something like this:

```
'tns:Token' => 'SS'
```

Answer (score 1):

In XML terms the difference between these two requests is not the `Search` element, but rather that in the "current" version the `Token` element is not in a namespace, whereas in the "need" version the `Token` is in the `http://www.serviceurl.com/` namespace.

You should be able to achieve the effect you require by setting the client's `element_form_default` parameter to `:qualified`

```
Savon.client(element_form_default: :qualified)
```

([docs](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html))

This will probably produce

```
<tns:Search>
  <tns:Token>
```

but as far as an XML parser is concerned that is equivalent to the version with a default namespace declaration (and if the service doesn't accept this form then the bug lies in the *service*, not in your client).

Comment: Yes the search and token are in tns namespace. But the service i am calling does not recognize the token.

Comment: Then you need to complain to the service provider and get them to fix their broken service...  If all else fails you can always construct the XML by hand (the "xml" option on [this page](http://savonrb.com/version2/locals.html)) but that means you have to handle any necessary escaping of illegal characters within the `Token` value.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
client=Savon.client(wdsl: ...)
client.call(:search, attributes: {xmlns: "http://www.serviceurl.com/"}) do 
  message ({ 
    "Token" => 55
  })
end
```